# cfdocument not display data:image/svg+xml;base64

Tags: image, coldfusion, cfdocument

I have an image in the format data:image/svg+xml;base64

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" width="60" height="60">
```

In my coldfusion html page, it displays fine, but inside a cfdocument PDF format, the image does not display. Does anyone know why?

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" marginLeft=.50 marginTop=.6 pageWidth=8 PageHeight=4 localUrl=yes overwrite="Yes">
```

Thanks

Comment: You did not include how you are referencing the image within the `<cfdocument>` tags. Try the solution posted over here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322207/1636917

Comment: I just insert the <img> tag inside the cfdocument. I think cfdocument pdf can't display SVG images. Is possible to convert the image using HTML or JavaScript or even ColdFusion?

Comment: Which version of CF?

Comment: ColdFusion version 10

Comment: Your browser supports modern HTML, CSS & JS.  CFDocument doesn't support much in terms of HTML or CSS (& JS isn't supported at all.) Check out WKHTMLTOPDF if you want an alternative that works well w/ColdFusion 6-2018+.  (NOTE: WKHTMLTOPDF supports inline SVG, webfonts, absolute positioning, etc.)

Comment: I think WKHTMLTOPDF does not work for ColdFsuion

Comment: It does, I think there are some custom tags or libraries for that.